# Docker, cannot connect to docker daemon at uniw:///var/run/docker.sock

Tags: linux, docker, sockets, containers

I am running an old version of docker: `Docker version 20.10.8-ce, build 62eae52c2a`. I want to run  the hello-world container. When I run it I got the output below:

```
# docker run --rm hello-world                                                                                                                      
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

I checked if docker daemon is running using systemctl:

```
# systemctl status docker
* docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (8;;file://xilinx-zcu102-20222/lib/systemd/system/docker.service/lib/systemd/system/docker.service8;;; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
             `-8;;file://xilinx-zcu102-20222/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.confhttp-proxy.conf8;;
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2023-06-09 14:34:20 UTC; 52min ago
TriggeredBy: * docker.socket
       Docs: 8;;https://docs.docker.comhttps://docs.docker.com8;;
   Main PID: 1483 (dockerd)
      Tasks: 10 (limit: 4409)
     Memory: 26.3M
     CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
             `-1483 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd://

Jun 09 14:34:19 xilinx-zcu102-20222 dockerd[1483]: time="2023-06-09T14:34:19.525285947Z" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup blkio weight"
Jun 09 14:34:19 xilinx-zcu102-20222 dockerd[1483]: time="2023-06-09T14:34:19.525361034Z" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup blkio weight_device"
Jun 09 14:34:19 xilinx-zcu102-20222 dockerd[1483]: time="2023-06-09T14:34:19.525908059Z" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
Jun 09 14:34:19 xilinx-zcu102-20222 dockerd[1483]: time="2023-06-09T14:34:19.529881066Z" level=warning msg="Running modprobe bridge br_netfilter failed with message...xit status 1"
Jun 09 14:34:19 xilinx-zcu102-20222 dockerd[1483]: time="2023-06-09T14:34:19.826879121Z" level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172...d IP address"
Jun 09 14:34:19 xilinx-zcu102-20222 dockerd[1483]: time="2023-06-09T14:34:19.924768572Z" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
Jun 09 14:34:19 xilinx-zcu102-20222 dockerd[1483]: time="2023-06-09T14:34:19.987556315Z" level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=d24c6dc5cf-unsupported graphdriver(s)...on=20.10.8-ce
Jun 09 14:34:19 xilinx-zcu102-20222 dockerd[1483]: time="2023-06-09T14:34:19.988075737Z" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
Jun 09 14:34:20 xilinx-zcu102-20222 systemd[1]: Started Docker Application Container Engine.
Jun 09 14:34:20 xilinx-zcu102-20222 dockerd[1483]: time="2023-06-09T14:34:20.046509226Z" level=info msg="API listen on /run/docker.sock"
```

I realized the final log, "API listen on /run/docker.sock" but when I run docker it tries to connect `/var/run/docker.sock`. Is this the source of the problem?

Comment: Not sure what triggered the `.sock` file to be placed under `/run`. We should be able to point the docker-cli to it by `export DOCKER_HOST=unix:///run/docker.sock`.

Comment: I am trying to run docker in embedded linux. Not sure but maybe this can be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as [Turing85](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4216641/turing85) also mentioned, I managed to run docker by specifying host additionally.

It worked when I run the command below:

```
docker run --rm hello-world --host /run/docker.sock
```

I dont know why my docker.sock is located in /run